# extract a substring of 11 characters from a line using sed,awk or perl

Tags: perl, shell, sed, awk

I have a file with many lines, in each line
there is either substring

```
whatever_blablablalsfjlsdjf;asdfjlds;f/watch?v=yPrg-JN50sw&amp,whatever_blabla
```

or

```
whatever_blablabla"/watch?v=yPrg-JN50sw&amp" class=whatever_blablablavwhate
```

I want to extract a substring, like the "yPrg-JN50s" above

the matching pattern is 
the 11 characters after the string "/watch?="

how to extract the substring

I hope it is sed, awk in one line
if not, a pn line perl script is also ok

Comment: ITYM /watch?v=, not /watch?=. Also, can that string occur multiple times on one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
grep -oP '(?<=/watch\?v=).{11}'
```

if your `grep` knows Perl regex, or

```
sed 's/.*\/watch?v=\(.\{11\}\).*/\1/g'
```

Comment: <div  id=""   yt-grid-box "><div class="yt-lockup-thumbnail"><a href="/watch?v=0_NfNAL3Ffc" class="ux-thumb-wrap yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-contextlink contains-addto result-item-thumb"  data-sessionlink="ved=CAMQwBs%3D&amp;ei=CPTsy8bhqLMCFRR0fAodowXbww%3D%3D"><span class="video-thumb ux-thumb yt-thumb-default-185 "><span class="yt-thumb-clip"><span class="yt-thumb-clip-inner"><img src="//i1.ytimg.com/vi/0_NfNAL3Ffc/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Miniature" width="185" ><span class="vertical-align"></span></span></span></span><span class="video-time">5:15</span>

Comment: like the above line, your script doesn't work in getting "0_NfNAL3Ffc", because (?=&amp) is not universal

Comment: @user1769686: Why didn't you include this in your original question? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13139469/edit) your question to include this input.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
/watch?v=yPrg-JN50sw&amp
"/watch?v=yPrg-JN50sw&amp" class=
$
$ awk 'match($0,/\/watch\?v=/) { print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH,11) }' file
yPrg-JN50sw
yPrg-JN50sw
```

Answer (score 2):

Just with the shell's parameter expansion, extract the 11 chars after "watch?v=":

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    tmp=${line##*watch?v=}
    echo ${tmp:0:11}
done < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed to remove the extraneous information:

```
sed 's/[^=]\+=//; s/&.*$//' file
```

Or with awk and sensible field separators:

```
awk -F '[=&]' '{print $2}' file
```

Contents of `file`:

```
cat <<EOF > file
/watch?v=yPrg-JN50sw&amp
"/watch?v=yPrg-JN50sw&amp" class=
EOF
```

Output:

```
yPrg-JN50sw
yPrg-JN50sw
```

#### Edit accommodating new requirements mentioned in the comments

```
cat <<EOF > file
<div id="" yt-grid-box "><div class="yt-lockup-thumbnail"><a href="/watch?v=0_NfNAL3Ffc" class="ux-thumb-wrap yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-contextlink contains-addto result-item-thumb" data-sessionlink="ved=CAMQwBs%3D&amp;ei=CPTsy8bhqLMCFRR0fAodowXbww%3D%3D"><span class="video-thumb ux-thumb yt-thumb-default-185 "><span class="yt-thumb-clip"><span class="yt-thumb-clip-inner"><img src="//i1.ytimg.com/vi/0_NfNAL3Ffc/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Miniature" width="185" ><span class="vertical-align"></span></span></span></span><span class="video-time">5:15</span> 
EOF
```

Use awk with sensible record separator:

```
awk -v RS='[=&"]' '/watch/ { getline; print }' file
```

Note, you should use a proper XML parser for this sort of task.

Comment: You should note that setting RS to more than one character makes it GNU awk specific. Other awks typically won't complain, they just won't work.

Comment: @EdMorton: well gawk and mawk, but yes this has portability issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep --perl-regexp --only-matching --regexp="(?<=/watch\\?=)([^&]{0,11})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lines have exactly the format you quoted, this should work.

```
awk '{print substr($0,10,11)}'
```

Edit: From the comment in another answer, I guess your lines are much longer and complicated than this, in which case something more comprehensive is needed:

```
gawk '{if(match($0, "/watch\\?v=(\\w+)",a)) print a[1]}'
```

Comment: Most awks will not support \w. I suspect it's GNU awk specific.

Comment: GNU awk makes up the vast majority of awks out there, doesn't it? But I'll change the name to make it explicit.

Comment: No. Most UNIX boxes don't come with GNU awk installed, they come with nawk, mawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, or other.